# unable to remove x-powered-by and server headers for non-page resources (png, css, js, etc.) on ASP .NET Core web app in Azure

Tags: asp.net, azure, response-headers

I have a web app running on ASP .NET Core in Azure.
The web config is as specified below.
When I view the page in Edge, and look at the headers for a web page, the X-Powered-By and Server response headers are indeed removed. If I look at the headers for any other resources such as CSS, PNG, or JS files, the X-Powered-By and Server headers are still there. How do I remove these headers?

```
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="aspNetCore"/>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
    <httpProtocol>
      <!-- Remove X-Powered-By header -->
      <customHeaders>
        <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
        <remove name="Server" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
    <security>
      <!-- Remove Server header-->
      <requestFiltering removeServerHeader ="true" />
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove the `X-Powered-By` and `Server headers` in ASP .NET Azure app service, you are following the correct way.

I tried with the same code in `web.config`, it worked.

```xml
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\WebApplication8.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile="\\?\%home%\LogFiles\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
     <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
        <remove name="Server" />
      </customHeaders>
     </httpProtocol>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering removeServerHeader ="true" />
    </security>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

**without adding the above code:**

[image]

**After adding the code in web.config:**

[image]

***If it still doesn't work, you can try adding the below code of `rewrite url` in `web.config`:***

```xml
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
        <remove name="Server" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering removeServerHeader ="true" />
    </security>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Remove Server header">
          <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Server" pattern=".+" />
          <action type="Rewrite" value="" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Remove X-Powered-By header">
          <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_X-Powered-By" pattern=".+" />
          <action type="Rewrite" value="" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
```